# Cannot consume from a topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

When i try to consume messages from the kafka server which is hosted in ec2 with kafka console tool (V 0.9.0.1 , i think this uses old consumer APIs)
I get following exception.
How can i overcome this?

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper zookeeper.xx.com:2181 --topic my-replicated-topic
[2016-04-06 15:52:40,247] WARN [console-consumer-12572_Rathas-MacBook-Pro.local-1459921957380-6ebc238f-leader-finder-thread], Failed to add leader for partitions [my-replicated-topic,1],[my-replicated-topic,2],[my-replicated-topic,0]; will retry (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:98)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:83)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:149)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.earliestOrLatestOffset(SimpleConsumer.scala:188)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread.handleOffsetOutOfRange(ConsumerFetcherThread.scala:84)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$addPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:187)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$addPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:182)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:778)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:116)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:777)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.addPartitions(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:182)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager$$anonfun$addFetcherForPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:88)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager$$anonfun$addFetcherForPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:778)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3.foreach(Map.scala:161)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:777)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager.addFetcherForPartitions(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:78)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:95)
    at
```

I created topic like

```
/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper zookeeper.xx.com:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic my-replicated-topic
```

Comment: Can you post result of describe command for **my-replicated-topic** topic?

Comment: @avr sorry, i have fixed this. I had some DNS issues and i fixed that in my hosts file. Now i do not see this issue any more. My original issue remains as same with new kafka consumer. Please check the following thread at kafka user list //Is there any behavioural change to connect local server and remote server?//  and  //Consumer thread is waiting forever, not returning any objects//

Comment: @avr, I tried the describe command, to sort out infinite poll() issue and i get Leader as -1. Does that give any clue?   $ ./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zookeeper.xx.com:2181 --topic MY_TOPIC
Topic:MY_TOPIC PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
 Topic: MY_TOPIC Partition: 0 Leader: -1 Replicas: 1012 Isr:

Comment: The topic you use -- is it MY_TOPIC or my-replicated-topic? The topic names in your question and your comment do not match.

Comment: I create several topics for testing purpose..All topics give same results.